# Working with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Working with Alamofire, getting:

> Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   2." error

Here is my code in `NetworkClass`:

```
class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params :[String:String], success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

        Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

            print(responseObject)

            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

and request call:

```
let strURL = "myurl"
            let parameters : [String: String] =
            [
                "user_name":"SNSH" as String,
                "password":"SNOSH" as String,
                "device_id":"0D4F5322-81C0-0000-9210-70DA0C6BC04C" as String,

            ]

        if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) {
            // here `json` is your JSON data, an array containing the String
            // if you need a JSON string instead of data, then do this:
            if let content = String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                // here `content` is the JSON data decoded as a String
                print(content)
                print(parameters)
                NetworkClass.requestPOSTURL(strURL, params: parameters, success: {
                    (JSONResponse) -> Void in
                    print(JSONResponse)
                }) {
                    (error) -> Void in
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to send String in parameters.

Comment: chheck ur JSON response is correct or not, problem in your JSON response second line , check once in your back end

Comment: I think am getting improper response as i have to pass string that is content in params and i am sending parameters
print(content)
print(parameters)

Comment: ya correct you get inproper response from server

Comment: How to change parameter type to string in requestPOSTURL func

Answer (score 0):

```
let urlAsString1 : String = API
    let urlStr : NSString = urlAsString1.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
            let params:NSMutableDictionary? = [
                "user_name":"SNSH" as String,
                "password":"SNOSH" as String,
                "device_id":"0D4F5322-81C0-0000-9210-70DA0C6BC04C" as String,

            ];
            let ulr =  NSURL(string:urlStr as String)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: ulr!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)


            let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
            }
            request.HTTPBody = json!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


            Alamofire.request(request)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    // do whatever you want here
                    switch (response.result) {
                    case .Success(let JSON):
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                        let responseString = JSON as! NSDictionary
                        print(responseString)


                        break;
                    case .Failure:

                        break

                    }
            }
            }
```